# How to call a configuration method situated in my global.asax in my Test Project?

Tags: .net, asp.net, unit-testing, automapper, global-asax

In my **Global.asax** **Application_Start()** I have a configuration of **AutoMapper**, this configuration is triggered whenever the application run.

I'm using **AutoMapper** in my **Controllers**.

I have a **Test Project** to test my **Controllers** and I need to trigger this configuration of AutoMapper whenever my test project is fired.

There is a place in my **Test Project** where I have something like the **Application_Start()** in **Global.asax** to call this Configuration Method of AutoMapper from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add initialization method to test class and set [[TestInitialize()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)]-attribute to it.

```
namespace TestNamespace
{
   [TestClass()]
   public class TestClass
   {
      [TestInitialize()]
      public void Initialize()
      {
        // some initialization code
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll need do that in each test? I'm want to avoid that

Comment: You should do it in each test CLASS not test. Test class composes many tests.

Comment: By the way I suppose you'll use mock in many test therefore global initialization isnt necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For those of us still looking for another option to do this.

- In the `App_Start` folder, add a class file `AutoMapperConfig.cs`

  ```
  namespace MyNameSpace
  {
    public class AutoMapperConfig
    {
      public static void Register()
      {
        // Your AutoMapper configuration should go in here
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- In `global.asax` `Application_Start()` method add

  ```
  AutoMapperConfig.Register();
  ```
- Now in your test class you should be able to call the same configuration method (you will need to reference the mvc project).

  ```
  [TestMethod]
  public void AutoMapper_Configuration_Should_Succeed()
  {
    AutoMapperConfig.Register();
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
  }
  ```
- Or (If you have more than one tests for which the configuration is needed)

  ```
  [TestInitialize()]
  public void Initialize()
  {
    AutoMapperConfig.Register();
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void AutoMapper_Configuration_Should_Succeed()
  {
    Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
  }
  ```